# ScrollTo (jquery) doesn't seem to work in FF?

Tags: jquery, scroll

Check the following link in Chrome: http://www.bavarianblue.com/parts-list/?tags=struts

The site is totally jacked in IE - need to fix a bunch of CSS.

I use the follow Javascript to perform the animation (uses [jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2-min.js](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2009/05/jqueryscrollto-142-released.html));

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { //required for $ to work in Wordpress
    var moo = $(".tags").attr("rel");
    if (moo == ""){
        return;
    }else {
        var scrolling = $("."+moo).offset().top-100;
        $.scrollTo(scrolling, 800, {easing:'swing'} );
        $('.'+moo).animate({backgroundColor : "#4c4c4c", color : "white"}, function() {
            $(this).animate({backgroundColor : "#dcdcdc"}, function() {
                $(this).animate({backgroundColor : "#4c4c4c"}); //animation wasn't completing chain, thus all the nested functions.                                                        });
        $('.'+moo+' a').animate({color : "#ed9925"});
        }); 
    }
});
```

Any clue why it doesn't work? Not getting any errors in FF...

**EDIT**

As @Chouchenos pointed out, a script type wasn't declared, and I didn't close the tag. However, now FF doesn't generate an error, but the animation (changing the BG and the scroll) doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both FF and IE tell me that

> $.scrollTo is not a function

But surprisingly, it works on chrome.

EDIT : Firefox makes an error here I think :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.js"/>
<script src="http://www.bavarianblue.com/wp-content/themes/Polished/js/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2-min.js"></script>
```

It may be like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.bavarianblue.com/wp-content/themes/Polished/js/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2-min.js"></script>
```

That's why scrollTO doesn't load I think

Comment: Plus, with web developper tool bar, it tells me jquery UI is load like this : <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.js"> The <script> doesn't close... error, js not load, bam!
And apparently, it doesn't bother Chrome...

Comment: I was just figuring that out, didn't see the closing tag problem though! Thanks for pointing that out... however still a problem, see edit

Comment: It's still the same problem, you should put <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.js"></script> instead of <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.js"/> ... firebug still says scrollTo is not a function, it means the js isn't loaded or that you spelled scrollTo wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the animate and setting the backgroundcolor doesn't work either. Have you tried debugging using Firebug? I suspect that the line `if (moo == "")` might be returning something unexpected in FF.

I suppose that the problem is that **you have display:none on the div with the class="tags"**. FF possibly won't allow you to scroll to an element that is not displayed on the page while Chrome does.

You can test this by temporarily removing the display:none style from the div and seeing whether it works in FF

Comment: Well... now FF gets `rel` info, but still doesn't animate. Still hunting it down....

Answer (score 0):

moo ==''  : return;  and its returning, am I missing something ? Can you give steps to reproduce as what is NOT working ? There is no .tags anywhere .. the tags div contain js

Comment: .tags is there.... in the link I provided, see    `<DIV class="tags" rel="struts" style="display:none;"></DIV>` It's supposed to animate in FF and it's not, only in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

ScrollTo isn't a native jQuery method; you need [Flesler's ScrollTo plug-in](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html).

Comment: as mentioned in the OP, I am using  jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2-min.js

Comment: You're right, my apologies.  However, loading your page in FireFox and looking at the network traffic, it's never loading jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2-min.js.  Even more odd, when I pull it up in Firefox, it says that the src attribute isn't a link.  I suspect that something is odd about that script tag, something Chrome's parser tolerates, but Firefox's does not.